# css - calculate height of android browser bar?

Tags: android, html, css, angular, responsive

I'm trying to write a responsive website that set's the maximum height to 100% and everything is on-screen without needing to scroll. Setting `{height: 100vh}` works on a flex box in the desktop. However, when I view the site on mobile, then it scrolls, ignoring the height of the browser tab in chrome. I would like to set the height to something like `{height: calc(100vh - address bar)}` so that it shrinks the height of the document so everything fits without scrolling or hiding the browser tab.

Comment: I'm trying to work out something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892105/flex-box-100vh-stretches-behind-mobile-safari-chrome-are-there-any-known-trick

Answer (score -2):

Have you included the viewport meta tags in the head of the web page. From experience this can change the effect that certain CSS has on the mobile version.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If that's doesn't work out, perhaps use media queries and use `100%` instead of `100vh`.

Comment: It's hard to call this an "answer" since you don't know or explain how anything works. "Try this, maybe think about that" sort of things should be comments, not answers. If you don't have enough rep to comment yet, there's a reason for that.

Comment: this did not work, and `%` vs `vh` does not fill the screen size of the device.